# My php code isn't sending user inputs to the database

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my code

```
<?php
include("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php");
?>
<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
    //Declaring Variables
        $fn = "";           //First Name
        $ln = "";           //Last Name
        $em = "";           //Email
        $em2 = "";          //Email Confirm
        $pswd = "";     //Password
        $pswd2 = "";        //Password Confirm
        $d = "";            //Sign Up Date
    //Registration Form
        $fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['first_name']);        //First Name
        $ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['last_name']);     //Last Name
        $em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);         //Email
        $em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);           //Email Confirm
        $pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);        //Password
        $pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);  //Password Confirm
        $d = date("Y-m-d");                        //Sign Up Date

if($reg) {
    if($fn&&$ln&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
        if($em==$em2){
            if($pswd==$pswd2) {
                if(strlen($fn)>32||strlen($ln)>32) {
                    echo "First name and Last name must be no more than 32 characters!";
                }
                else {
                    if(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
                        echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters ...";
                    }
                    else {
                        $pswd = md5($pswd);
                        $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
                        die("<h2>Welcome to bakpakk!</h2>");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "Your passwords do not match!";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Your emails do not match!";
        }
    }
    else {echo "Please fill in all fields ...";}
}
?>
```

It's user log in system that posts this information to the database. "mysql_connect.inc.php" looks like this

```
<?
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","250317") or die(myspq_error());
    mysql_select_db("bakpakk");
?>
```

When i enter data into the input fields (First name, last name, email, password, etc.) it doesn't post into the table in the database. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: `or die(myspq_error());` What's that?

Comment: Try dumping your variables to see what's coming across. Also, prepare yourself for warning about using the old mysql_* functions.

Comment: not entirely sure if this makes a difference or not, i've been out of php for a while, but shouldn't it be `<?php` ? not `<?`

Comment: @sircapsalot that shouldn't be a problem if for OP's configuration short tags are allowed. They can still be set to allow

Comment: First, try echoing the POST variable to ensure the data was received. If yes, try echoing the query to see what value are being substituted and fire that query directly to catch any syntax/semantic error.

Comment: Why don't you escape your database input? What happens when you add `set_error_handler("var_dump")` atop? (=Is the form really sent per POST?)

Comment: Change `or die(myspq_error())` to `or die(mysql_error())` in your `mysql_connect.inc.php` file. Also, add it to the end of you `INSERT` query - `$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @sircapsalot thank you, that actually worked, because for some reason i can't use the shorthand and i figured that out while programming index.php i forgot to change it to <?php in the mysql_connect.inc.php file. Stupid mistake, but it's working now. Thank you

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possible problems (note i'm no pro when it comes to MySQl in PHP):

I would start by removing the declared variables, you declare them above as "" then you declare them again as your value that I am assuming you want.

Where you say:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
```

It looks like you have the first variable equal to nothing, which (especially if this is the primary key) would cause MySQL to die.

The next two things to try would be:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","250317") or die(myspq_error());
```

It looks like a typo at the end, try replacing it with

```
or die (mysql_error());
```

If after trying that it does not work please let us know :)
Good luck!

UPDATE:

Here is an example of a working database connection and insert I wrote a few months ago, I thought it might help you detect any errors or typos.

```
<?php

/**
* @author Steven Byrne
* @copyright 2012
* @version 5.2
 */

  if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
     $btn       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['btn']);
     $username  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
     $email     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
     $name      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

          $link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die(mysql_error(). "Could not connect to database.");
 $dbsel= mysql_select_db('database', $link) or die("Couldn't select database");


    //Your validation code


    //MySQL

            $donation_date = date(Ymd);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mcdonations (username,email,name,amount,date)
                           VALUES ('$username','$email','$name','$name','$donation_date')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error() . "<P>" . $sql);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry Steven `250317` is not `port`, it is `password`

Comment: Well at least that makes more sense, do you run that section of code before or after you try to insert?

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment was actually the answer to your question, i will make it official.

You are recieving this error because you do not have PHP shorthand enabled.  Hence why

```
<?
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","250317") or die(myspq_error());
    mysql_select_db("bakpakk");
?>
```

is not working.   Replace this block with

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","250317") or die(myspq_error());
    mysql_select_db("bakpakk");
?>
```

and voila.